# Is there any way to disable to the long fighting animations?

Tags: lego-marvel-super-heroes

In LEGO: Marvel Super Heroes, is there any way to disable the long fighting animations from the various characters? In the interest of time and getting through some of the levels quicker, I was just hoping to turn off the long fighting animation sequences that a few of the characters go through. There doesn't appear to be anything in the options, and I didn't know if there was a special code to do it, or a red brick that may enable it.

Comment: I doubt that there is, but it sure would be great to have that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen/earned all the Red Bricks, and there are none that disable combat animations as far as I'm aware.  I don't know that anyone has an exhaustive list of the cheat codes, but the ones I've seen have all been things that unlocked stuff you could earn naturally through play.

I've developed a few tricks for avoiding these animations, though.  For one, you might consider sticking with someone who has a long range attack.  These never have a long attack animation.  Sometimes I'll just take Iron Man or Black Widow and stand in a spot, spin around, and fire at everyone.  The same is true of beam attacks.  They're quite deadly and never have a long animation associated with them.

The attack animations are also usually tied to the end of a long finishing combo against an enemy.  If you do short combos, they don't tend to trigger.  The larger figures (Hulk, Thing, etc) can tend to down an enemy without a long combo.  Thus, sticking with them can be another strategy, especially in free play mode.